# passing objects by value in java

Tags: java, object, parameters, reference, copy

so suppose i have

```
ArrayList<E> X = new ArrayList<E>();
```

and I pass X into some parameter:

```
Something Y = new Something(X);
```

it will pass X by reference rather than by value and I don't want this....class Something has a field with Arraylist type that is supposed to be distinct to itself and I don't want to go and iterate through the damn arraylist and set it individually just to instantiate the field...

is there a way to easily make Java pass any object parameters by value rather than reference without having have to implement cloneable interface on all my objects which is a pain in the butt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually passes X by value. (The Something constructor can't change the variable X in the calling code.) X happens to be a reference to an ArrayList, not an ArrayList. You could try:

```
Something Y = new Something(new ArrayList<E>(X));
```

Answer (score 4):

As Java do not allow direct pointer manipulation, you cannot dereference a pointer. You have to live with references. If you want to prevent the passed object from being modified, you have to clone it or make it immutable (like `String`). Also keep in mind that [object references are passed-by-value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm). So statements like "Java has pass-by-reference" is not exact, if we take *pass-by-reference* in the C++ sense.

Comment: @Stephen: I don't understand this big fuss. How is C++ pass-by-reference any different? It is also a pass-by-value of a pointer - hidden by semantics, by that is what java does as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new object everytime you can pass an unmodifiable list. This list is read-only and the user has to create another list if he wants to make any modification.

```
List unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
List newList = new ArrayList(unmodifiableList);
Collections.sort(newList);
```

The constructor of ArrayList takes an existing list, reads its elements (without modifying them!), and adds them to the new List.